# Dual boot - problem "seeing" and copying files from one to another OS

Tags: operating-systems

If i have dual boot, *Windows xp* and *Kubuntu 15.10*.

Can I see files I have on *Windows xp* if *Kubuntu* is installed after all those files are saved, is it possible to see my pictures, music, etc. from Kubuntu ?

Then, if I can see them can I copy desired files using Kubuntu, will system allow that? Is there a way?

I need to do it like that because my windows is not working properly
(Again, if that is possible at all).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is intended for questions on electronics design.  You are asking about operating systems, which would probably be better asked on the SuperUser site.

Comment: You generally can do this, there are no issues whatsoever doing this.   Does it NOT work for you?  The Windows partition usually get mounted as /windows/

Comment: If you have not yet installed Kubuntu, don't. Run it from the CD and backup first otherwise installation may overwrite your data.

Comment: Yes, both of these should be possible as long as you are mounting or can mount the disk partitions from the respective OSes to see or copy, etc. the applicable files. Have you done any research into the disk configuration of the locations you are trying to access from each OS or whatever?

Comment: Everyone is right so far. I will add this. You also might consider creating a partition, or volume, with shared privileges and use it as a shared folder on the hard drive. I've done this in the past, funny enough with exactly both of the same OS's you are using. However I suggest using an old laptop that nobody wants and dedicating that to a Linux OS. I highly recommend Centos as I used it regularly in the UC labs and on my own dedicated machine.

Answer (score 0):

From Linux, you should be able to see the Windows partition (you may need to mount it, and it can be set [to automatically mount at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121366/how-can-i-automatically-mount-an-ntfs-partition-in-lubuntu-on-startup)). See also [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=888618). Note that not all Ubuntu distros come able to read NTFS files, but it's trivial to add that package:

> sudo apt-get install ntfs-config

**All** files, including those that Windows hides and protects, are available. Data such as videos, photos and documents can certainly be shared. I've had no trouble with programs such as Calibre in both Windows and Linux flavors sharing the same *Calibre Library* residing on the Windows NTFS partition.  That said, be *very* careful when changing any files, particularly system files. In fact, many Ubuntu distros prevent dual-booting into Linux whilst Windows *hiberfil.sys* is on the root to prevent later damage to Windows.

BTW, you can also read (though I don't recommend *writing*) files on an ext[n] Linux partition from Windows using tools such as [DiskInternals' Linux Reader](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/). It works well on Windows 10, though I've not tried it on XP.